# JSON Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

So I am making a discord bot and have been working on this tiny peice of code for 4hrs and i cant figure it out

```js
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new commando.CommandoClient();
const fs = require('fs');
const jobData = require('../../Economy/jobData.json');
```

And it give me 1 of 2 errors either
A: SyntaxError: C:\Users\IceX\Desktop\ScorchBot\Economy\jobData.json: Unexpected end of JSON input

B:Error: Cannot find module '../Economy/jobData.json'

I have tried moving the file multiple times even deleting it and remaking it i have tried multiple paths like ../../jobData.json ../../Economy/jobData ../Economy/jobData.json literally every combo its just not working

**UPDATE**

```js
    async run(message, args)
    {
        

        let sender = message.author;
        let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
        let prefix = '!'
    
        // Trigger Events
        let jobData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Economy/jobData.json', 'utf8'));

        if (!jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id]) jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id] = {}
        if (!jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id].job) jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id].job = "Mime";
    
        fs.writeFile('Economy/jobData.json', JSON.stringify(jobData), (err) => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        })
    }
    
}
```

This is the part of code that uses the json file

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:27)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IceX\Desktop\ScorchBot\commands\simple\mime.js:5:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
```

**Full Code**

```js
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new commando.CommandoClient();
const fs = require('fs');
const jobData = require('../../jobData.json');


class MimeCommand extends commando.Command
{
    constructor(client)
    {
        super(client,{
            name: '1',
            group: 'simple',
            memberName: '1',
            description: 'select mime job'
        });
    }

    

     run(message, args)
    {
        

        let sender = message.author;
        let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
        let prefix = '!'
    
        // Trigger Events
        let jobData = JSON.parse(fs.readFile('Economy/jobData.json', 'utf8'));

        if (!jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id]) jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id] = {}
        if (!jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id].job) jobData[sender.id + message.guild.id].job = "Mime";
    
        fs.writeFile('Economy/jobData.json', JSON.stringify(jobData), (err) => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        })
    }
    
}

module.exports = MimeCommand;
```

Comment: since the error states it can't find `'../Economy/jobData.json'` and the path you supply is `'../../Economy/jobData.json'` - that part is a no brainer. as for `Unexpected end of JSON input` - that's because `jobData.json` doesn't have valid JSON - don't even have to see the content to know that

Comment: What do you mean by not valid JSON it literally worked 1 time then i deleted the data out of jobData.json and it has not worked since

Comment: *i deleted the data out of jobData.json* ... so, `jobData.json` is empty - that doesn't sound like valid JSON

Comment: its just empty doesnt matter now because its a new json file that only has {} in it

Comment: oh, so it's not empty - sorry, thought you meant it was empty, but `{}` isn't empty, so it should be OK

Comment: i added another snippet

Comment: doesn't matter ... the problem you have is a) with the path to `jobData.json`, and b) with the content of `jobData.json` - how you use the content of `jobData.json` is irrelevant if a) is wrong or b) is invalid

Comment: So how do I fix it if its invlaid?

Comment: what is the content of the file when you get the `Unexpected end of JSON input` error - and is it the `require('../../Economy/jobData.json');` that triggers the error? - or are you running `run` many times without waiting for it to complete? - because that could cause an issue ... I see you've tagged it `async` yet nothing about that function requires the tag, and if you called it multiple times in a loop for instance, you'd end up with god knows what happening - because writeFile is asynchronous, but you've got no way to wait for it to complete with your code as written

Comment: {} i also added the full output of the error above

Comment: ok, how are you calling `run`

Comment: i call it through VS codes terminal using "node ."

Comment: once? twice? a hundred times a second?

Comment: once also i have removed the async tag and it has not made a difference

Comment: sure, but the async tag really didn't do anything. What were you expecting the async tag to achieve? That's the point. I suspect you are trying to wait for the run and all the asynchronous stuff in it to complete - but your code won't do that (try writeFileSync instead, since you're already using readFileSync)

Comment: added both writeFileSync and readFileSync no difference it worked 1 time now its just not like ever since i deleted the data from the json file its been broken

Comment: Also i dont want it to writeFileSync because it causes issues with the "server" locking up it needs to when the bot starts up check who is all in jobData.json and when they run the command if theyre not in the json file it adds them

Comment: but you use readFileSync!!??!! (originally - as the code is now, it is **guaranteed** to fail `JSON.parse(fs.readFile('Economy/jobData.json', 'utf8'));` is probably why you're getting the error in the first place (your code originally has `readFileSync` - so that was a misdirection)

Comment: yes because i need it to do that be performing any other action so it allows the bot to read the file before writing to it

Comment: your problem is you're using asynchronous `readFile` and expect a `synchronous` result

Comment: you'll probably want `run` to be like https://pastebin.com/dH0A79dD - or nicer using promisified readfile/writefile ... https://pastebin.com/ZdpbtjgP - that way, whatever **calls** `run` can `await` on the promise it returns

Comment: thank you im going to try and get this to work its no longer throwing out the same error just got to do some debugging